# Why does my Average and AverageIF formula differ?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a date range 7/5/2019 to 7/19/2019. The values for each date depicted:

```
7/5  19
7/8  35
7/9  29
7/10  40
7/11  33
7/12  19
7/15  35
7/16  37
7/17  30
7/18  60
7/19  41
```

(As noticed, not all dates are shown as they do not have any value assigned.)

Essentially, I am wondering why do the Average and AverageIF formulas differ with the returned value?

AverageIF formula:  `=AVERAGEIF($A$1:$K$1,">="&TODAY()-14,$A2:$K2)` returns 37

Average formula:  `=AVERAGE(A2:K2)` returns 34

Comment: today - 14 is the 12th and as such the dates before the 12 is being ignored in the AVERAGEIFS.

Comment: Apologies I should've mentioned, Today() represents when the information was last updated. Thus, in this case being the 19th.

Comment: then you need to change the formula to reference that date not today.

Comment: `TODAY()` is live and will always return the today's date.  So if you take 14 days back from today that is the 12th.  the numbers being averaged are `{19,35,37,30,60,41}` which equals 37.  `TODAY()` will not retain a date.  It is volatile and every time Excel Calculates it will force a recalculation on that formula.  Opening, closing, saving all force a recalculation.